# Better way to exec at a specific folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, command-line-interface, exec

It is possible to `exec` at the specific folder, rather than I need to use two commands separately?

e.g.

```
cd /opt/folderA
exec ....

cd /opt/folderB
exec ....
```

Comment: The question is not very clear to me. Your problem is that your shell needs to be in a specific folder before executing a command? `exec /opt/folderA/whatever.sh` would not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

The only ways to change current working directory for a process is:

a) the running program changes it by running a cd command from within the program itself

b) cd to the directory first and then run the program (inherits the CWD from the environment of the parent shell)

c) manipulate the /proc/[pid]/cwd file. The only way you could do this conceivably is by launching a separate bash shell, determine its pid, change the aforementioned file (a link), and then launch the program from within that bash shell.

So, to answer your question, there's no way around the "cd" command except option (c) which actually involves more steps than simply running "cd" first.

Answer (score 0):

If this two commands are different you can add the folder to your $PATH environment.

```
export PATH=$PATH:folderA:folderB
```

Or you can use alias

```
alias fromA=/opt/folderA/command
alias fromB=/opt/folderB/command
```

after that you can directly use

```
fromA
```

Adding this to your .bashrc will make it permanently.